# What is the difference between using :host and not using it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I found the usage of `:host` in angular is very confusing.

For example, there is a CSS file `a-component.component.css`, and its related HTML file is `a-component.component.html` whose `selector` is `app-a-component`.

And in the CSS file there is a statement

```
h1 {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

I think this CSS only applies to the `<app-a-component>` HTML element beased on the following explanation, is that correct?

[image: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles]

And if I change the CSS to

```
:host h1 {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

(adding `:host`)

it will still applies to the same `<app-a-component>` HTML element, because it is the host HTML element of this component, is that correct?

If they are both correct, why would we need `:host` given it is the same effect with or without it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: @ShashankVivek Just did. But still don't understand it. Hope you can help out. Thanks

Comment: OK, let me know if you got the clarity from given answer below

Answer (score 1):

In your example `:host h1 { ...}` there's no difference. Where the `:host` becomes useful is when you need to use `::ng-deep` or you want to style the *host* element.

e.g.

You have a component `<my-component></my-component>` and you want to apply styles directly to that element. You can add the styles with the `:host` selector.

```css
:host {
  background: red;
}
```

This will set the background of the `my-component` element to red.

For `:host ::ng-deep { ...` you can disable `ViewEncapsulation` for that rule but ONLY for descendant components. If you were to just use `::ng-deep` without the `:host` that will become a global style.

Comment: In your `<my-component>` example, I am wondering if I can just wrap the whole component's HTML template within a `div` with a class `container`, and apply the `background: red` on this `container` class? If yes, if seems that no `:host` needed as well.

Comment: Yup, at the cost of an extra wrapper element yes. Where you cant avoid using `:host` is to set the `display` property of the element. Usually `display:block`. By default the element is `inline` and you'll have to use the `:host` to overwrite it.